# Modifying cloned html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to open a nice popup for editing a domain object.

For this I have a popup template hidden inside an invisible div on a page.
When user clicks a button, I try to load the domain object with ajax, populate the template and show it.

Trouble is that only first field inside template is populated.

Template:

```
 <div class="popup" id="addDriverPopup">
        <div class="close"></div>

        <hr class="both"/>

        <div class="container  radius">
            <form action="/driver/manageDriver" method="post" name="driverForm" id="driverForm" >
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="" />
                <div class="title"><span>Uus autojuht </span><hr class="line"/></div>
                <p class="name">Nimi </p>
                <p class="input"><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" /></p>

                <p class="name">Perekonna nimi </p>
                <p class="input"><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" /></p>
                <p class="name">Isikukood </p>
                <p class="input"><input type="text" name="personalId" id="personalId" value="" /></p>
                <p class="name">Telefoni number </p>
                <p class="input"><input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" value="" /></p>
            </form>

        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $jq.ajax({
  url: 'show',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {driverId: driverId},
  success: function( data ) {
        var popup = $jq('#addDriverPopup').clone();
        popup.find("#id").val(data.id);
        popup.find("#firstName").val(data.firstName);
        popup.find("#lastName").val(data.lastName);
        popup.find("#personalId").val(data.personalId);
        popup.find("#phoneNumber").val(data.phoneNumber);

        alert(popup[0].innerHTML); // only id field is field in the template.


  },
  error: function(xhr, error) {
      alert(error);
      unblockUI();
  }
});
```

Output of alert():

```
        <div class="close"></div>
        <hr class="both">

        <div class="container  radius">
            <form action="/driver/manageDriver" method="post" name="driverForm" id="driverForm">
                <input name="id" id="id" value="1271672" type="hidden">
                <div class="title"><span>Uus autojuht </span><hr class="line"></div>
                <p class="name">Nimi </p>
                <p class="input"><input name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" type="text"></p>
                <p class="name">Perekonna nimi </p>
                <p class="input"><input name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" type="text"></p>
                <p class="name">Isikukood </p>
                <p class="input"><input name="personalId" id="personalId" value="" type="text"></p>
                <p class="name">Telefoni number </p>
                <p class="input"><input name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" value="" type="text"></p>
            </form>
        <p></p>
        </div>
```

Data returned from the server:

```
{"id":1271745,"firstName":"Burak","lastName":"Torum","personalId":"123456","phoneNumber":"123456"}
```

I double checked element ids for typos. Debug shows that the correct elements are found.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output of `data`? It may be missing the values. I've tested in jsfiddle.net and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/hrBMS/3/

Comment: thank you for your effort. But I see empty values in the textfields. Only id field is filled

Comment: Have yo got empty text fields in the alert in my jsfiddle? If so, what browser are you using?

Comment: yup, empty fields. Mac OS 10.8.2, FF, Opera, Safari

Comment: I think is a browser compability problem. I can confirm it works in Chrome 22 and IE 9 - Win 7 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the question comments by @rcdmk, it seems that it is a platform issue.

I had to refactor the code to return the ready-for-editing form to the client instead of json. Solution is less elegant, but cross-platform :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
alert(popup[0].innerHTML);
```

to

```
alert(popup.html());
```

Also I a not seeing the '#addDriverPopup' element on the code you provided... is that on the DOM somewhere?

Comment: same output. addDriverPopup is an outer container. It is working, as I can see the innerHTML / html() in the alert().

Comment: add the boolean value true to your clone call, see if that helps? also, you must use unique IDs. i recommend switching them to semantically useful class names instead, it's cleaner.

Comment: tried it with clone(), clone(true), without clone(). Same output.

Comment: what exactly does the data returned from your AJAX request look like?

Comment: again, if you're using clone and you're duplicating elements with those IDs, it's going to find the first ID in the DOM and update the value of THAT element, not your cloned one. You must either use new IDs for your cloned input elements, or use class names.

Comment: when I try alert(popup.find("#firstName").val()); after the values are passed to the template, it correctly displays the value. Seems that the operations of find are performed on another DOM element?? or not propagated to the selected element

Comment: try modifying it like: element.prop('value', YOUR_NEW_VALUE). also what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: jquery version 1.8.2. The values _are_ set, because when I try to find them using find() they are displayed correctly, but when I call html() they are lost. :( Still not working with your solution

Answer (score 0):

What is `#addDriverPopup` made of?

it's possible that the problem is that the ids are conflicting.  Because you are cloning, you end up with multiple ids with the same value.

There could just be some sort of conflict as a result.  May want to consider classes.

per my comment below:

```
$jq.ajax({
  url: 'show',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {driverId: driverId},
  success: function( data ) {

        $("#id").val(data.id);
        $("#firstName").val(data.firstName);
        $("#lastName").val(data.lastName);
        $("#personalId").val(data.personalId);
        $("#phoneNumber").val(data.phoneNumber);

        $jq('#addDriverPopup').dialog({
                 close: function(){
                       //Do stuff here to clean up, this syntax may be a bi
                      }
        });

  },
  error: function(xhr, error) {
      alert(error);
      unblockUI();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why are you cloning?  Why not just show the form, update the values, and after they submit clear it and hide it again?

Comment: What does your data output look like?

Comment: id is a number, the rest ones are strings. Can this be a hint?

Comment: I don't think it's data type as the issue.  Have you tried accessing the ids directly like I have above?